# How to Get my Source to Build with My own glext.h File

Tags: opengl, makefile

I am using RHEL 5.7 box with the NVIDIA drivers installed. However, I am using some extensions that require me to modify the glext.h file. I have tried placing it in my include path in my Makefile, and I have tried placing it in /usr/local/include/GL directory. However when building the library I am working on it keeps defaulting to the one stored in /usr/local/include/GL. How would I get it to default to the one in /usr/local/include/GL? I cannot provide the make file due to company policy. Please forgive.

---------------------------------------**UPDATE**---------------------------------------------

The resolve was to move the OpenGL headers from /usr/include/GL into a directory in the build tree, and then to set relative paths in the headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gcc -c file.c -I /usr/local/include/GL`

[`gcc` documentation for the `-I` option](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Search-Path.html):

> All the directories named by `-I` are searched, in left-to-right order, before the default directories.